# Datagridview cell forecolor change

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I want to set Datagridview cell forecolor 
In vb.net

On event if value nagative in cell than forecolor  red

And cell value positive than forecolor is blue

How can i do that ?

Comment: [DataGridView.CellFormatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting) Event

Comment: What have you tried so far ?